# What is the difference between “not to try”and “avoid doing”?

Tags: differences

I learned these sentences in my textbook.

1. I try not to talk about work at home.
2. Teachers have to avoid speaking too quickly

Can we also say the following sentences? What is the difference?

3. Teachers have to try not to speak too quickly.
4. I avoid talking about work at home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we speak of *trying not to* do something, the implication is that it is easy to start doing that thing unintentionally. You might find yourself talking about work at home because it is very much on your mind. A teacher who naturally speaks quickly has to make a conscious effort to speak more slowly when in front of the class.

*Avoiding* doing something doesn't have the same implication - it just means not doing it.

(Note that *not to try* isn't the same as *try not to*.)

Comment: I have one small reservation about this.  In a sense, it is not good enough for a teacher to try and fail to speak too quickly.  Any teacher who tries and regularly fails just shouldn't be a teacher.  Speaking at the right pace is too central a part of the profession.

Comment: @Tuffy - I was just picking up on the OP's example sentence! As an alternative, how about - A person with short legs might say to a long-legged companion "Please try not to walk so quickly! I'm in danger of getting left behind."

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Comment: @Kate Bunting  I think what I am trying to say may not exactly be about 'language use'.  With your other example, for example, for example, I would say that a short legged person need only ask a long legged person to walk more slowly.  It is not necessary to 'try'.  A short legged person might have to 'try' to keep up with a long legged person.  The sorts of things we have to 'try' not to do are reflexes:  trying not to laugh when someone makes an embarrassing mistake; trying not to cough in while Romeo is writhing in agony after taking the poison.  But people do, in fact, speak as you say.

Comment: @Tuffy - I don't agree that _try not to_ applies only to reflexes. A long-legged person naturally takes long strides, but can make a conscious effort to 'step short'. Of course they may simply be asked to walk more slowly, but I feel that using _try_ acknowledges the fact that the problematic behaviour is natural to them and not done deliberately to annoy.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't think there is much between us.  You are right about the language usage.  I was pointing to a distinction between trying to do something I find hard to do (like keeping up with a long-legged person (if I have short legs), and slowing down a bit (even though my normal gait is faster).  I'm appealing, I guess, to a root meaning that trying involves something the 'tryer' finds difficult rather than just inconvenient.  But I think that root has stretched to embrace your interpretation.